# Django rest-api - attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm getting the following error while running manage.py migrate in my Django rest-api. I'm unable to pinpoint where to look. Help appreciated.

> attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

The traceback shows the following :

''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myproject/myproject-api/manage.py", line 25, in 
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 395, in execute
django.setup()

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
app_config.ready()

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cacheops/**init**.py", line 18, in ready
install_cacheops()

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/funcy/flow.py", line 231, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/myEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 578, in install_cacheops
opts = rel.through._meta
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

''

Comment: Hi there, please consider adding the code here to get more responses You can check out the guidelines on how to ask a good question here <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> to get more responses with a potential answer. All the best

Comment: Hello there. I'm wondering which part of the code should i put since the stacktrace doesn't point to anything.

Comment: The issue here is that in your code, you provide a string object where another object is expected.

Comment: @Adrian: I am unable to pinpoint the location. Kindly check the temporary fix I figured as an answer. Waiting for your inputs.

Comment: @Earthling It seems that your configuration of cacheops may contain an error. The code stops in a setup function of cacheops. Hence, I recommend to check your configuration against the most up to date cacheops documentation.

Comment: @Adrian. I just checked my settings.py where the cacheops settings are configured. I'm building this open source social networking stack https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api/blob/master/openbook/settings.py. It is exactly this one. I'm downgrading the version from 6.1 to earlier one and the error goes away. However other errors cropping up since i upgraded Django to 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this. I had to install

> pip install django-cacheops==4.0.0

For the time being error is gone.

However, the original error stile persists if I install version django-cacheops==6.1.0

Comment: @Fidelis Maina, kindly review

Answer (score 0):

The error you get from cacheops seems to have to do with the fact that you're using a many-to-many relationship with a `through` model, where you specify the `through` model by passing a string with the class's name instead of the class itself, because the class is only defined below. Although this is perfectly common practice, cacheops seems to require that you do it differently:

Namely, try to reference your `through` model by passing the class instead of a string with the class's name. For this, you need to reorder your code a bit, putting the class definition of your `through` model first, which of course requires you to pass strings instead of classes to `ForeignKey` there. E.g. do it like this:

```
class PostCategory(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

class Post(models.Model):
    pass

class Category(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through=PostCategory, related_name='categories')
```

Comment: Will try this out and post an update soon. Thank you.